# Syncing between devices and macs problem

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

Is there a way to sync between macs and iDevices in a way you specify which device has the most recent data? I mean, suppose I make some modifications to a contact using my Mac or I buy some apps for my iPhone using iTunes on the Mac. When I sync the iphone, the sync is always made as the iPhone is the priority. So, the app will not be transferred to the iPhone and not even the change on that contact. Some times I want the reverse to occur.

How do I manage those situations?

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is worded is a bit funny but it sounds like the "Replace information on this iPhone" might be what you are looking for. You can find it in the Info tab of the iTunes sync window and what it does is it basically wipes what data there is on the iPhone (ot other iOS device) and replaces it with what is on the computer.